# Document function that returns object property by parameter

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm making an Api repository for my Vue.js application, following [this article](https://blog.snap.hr/01/11/2018/vue-api-calls-smart-way/).

Thing is, I like to document my functions so I have better code completion on VSCode. I typically use jsDoc for this.

I'm stuck here:

```
import DiarioEscolarRepository from './diarioEscolarRepository';
import PeriodoAvaliativoRepository from './periodoAvaliativoRepository';
import AtividadeAvaliativaRepository from './atividadeAvaliativaRepository';
import CorteEtarioRepository from './corteEtarioRepository';

const repositories = {
  diarioEscolar: DiarioEscolarRepository,
  periodoAvaliativo: PeriodoAvaliativoRepository,
  atividadeAvaliativa: AtividadeAvaliativaRepository,
  corteEtario: CorteEtarioRepository,
};

export default const RepositoryFactory = {
  get(name){
    return repositories[name];
  }
};
```

I need to make it so the editor understands that the get function is a simple acessor to the repositories object.

I tried using `@typedef` and `@type`, but none of them worked properly.

I tried something like `@returns {repositories.name}`, but is also does not work.

Is there a way to document this?

I also thought about using a typescript definition file but I never did it, so I don't know where to begin.